# Unity Buttons Not Working Despite Canvas, Graphic Raycaster, and Input Standalone Have Been Added

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a newbie in Unity engine, I'm trying to make my game's main menu interface, the plan is: I use a sprite image as the button where the image got a button component inside it. After scripting, it doesn't work, it turns out that the image with button component also doesn't work with color transition etc. I've been searching tutorial here and there like adding Canvas, Graphic Raycaster, and Input Standalone. None of them are working. But, when I try to test it with color transition, it requires a target graphic (which I have prepared) but I can't insert it (cursor with  black cross circle). Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Here's a screenshot of my interface and hierarchy:

[image: Unity Button Not Working]

Comment: define `not working` ... I can see something is scaled with a negative size there (red cross) ... and on the `Button` component you have a warning since you didn't reference the target `Image` component so nothing will be colored on hover or on click .... Probably not even OnClick whill be called for that reason...

Comment: as DerHugo said there can be no colouring as there is no target graphic (as the warning clearly states in the editor) however the onclick should work even without it. Can you show us what is in your "OnClick"? judging from the colouring of the little bit we can see of it, it appears to be empty ([this](https://gyazo.com/ac23ddee7175c8b1f65fc1e95f73c162) is what i'd expect to see if it had a method to it.). Are you sure you're calling to a method to invoke upon clicking? If so please include the script you are invoking as it might be an error in there.

Comment: Before this yes, I add a C# script and invoke the method by OnClick(). But, after it doesn't work, I remove the script, to test it with a simpler test like basic transition